# Stunnel no longer works after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: django, macos, ssl, osx-yosemite, stunnel

I've been using stunnel for local Django development on SSL-enabled pages for a while, but since upgrading to Yosemite it seems to have stopped working:

```
$ sudo stunnel stunnel/dev_https
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/stunnel
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried building `libssl` from source using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tmiz/1441111) and symlinking `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` to `/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`. That then failed, looking for `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`. So I symlinked the version I'd just built to that expected path, and got this:

```
$ sudo stunnel stunnel/dev_https
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

What's going on here? `stunnel` is at `/usr/bin/stunnel` and I've checked it's not installed via homebrew. Has anyone else managed to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

I just got stunnel working for Django on Yosemite. If I remember correctly, I also had to previously fix my libssl as explained in [this other answer for psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib).

Then, I use homebrew for everything:

```
$ brew install stunnel
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 9999 -nodes -out stunnel.pem -keyout stunnel.pem
```

I put this in `stunnel.conf` (derived from [here](http://pastebin.com/xten7Hi7)):

```
pid=/tmp/stunnel.pid
setuid=nobody
setgid=nobody
foreground=yes
client=no

[https]
cert = ./stunnel.pem
accept=443
connect=5000
```

I run `stunnel` with:

```
$ sudo stunnel stunnel.conf
```

And run Django with:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Hope that helps.