# Import psycopg2 Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-2.7, postgresql-9.3

When I try to run the command:

```
import psycopg2
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gwulfs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gwulfs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

So far I have tried `brew install openssl` and have referenced (with no luck):

[psycopg2 installation error - Library not loaded: libssl.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365619/psycopg2-installation-error-library-not-loaded-libssl-dylib)

http://joshuakehn.com/2013/10/13/Postgresapp-and-psycopg2-on-OS-X.html

[Psycopg2 image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407995/psycopg2-image-not-found)

Comment: If you are using bash (default shell on OS X), add the following line to `~/.bash_profile`: `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` . Or if you're using the fish shell, add the following to your `config.fish` (normally located at `~/.config/fish/config.fish`): `set -x DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/anaconda/lib $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` .

Comment: Same problem and solved in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944770/uwsgi-can-not-load-libssl-1-0-0-dylib/23945292#23945292

Comment: @xing-shi is right! Please don't mess around with symbolic linking (mentioned in other posts with this problem), or even environment variables (`$DYLD_FALLBACK_PATH`). Check out my solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36872624/5076471

Answer (score 78):

Instead of playing with symlinks in system library dirs, set the `$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the anaconda libraries. eg:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: woo This works! I think this should be the accepted answer. The other one looks dangerous.

Comment: This worked for me too! I'm using anaconda python with psycopg2 on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: thank you so much. hit at least 7 answers on stackoverflow before finding this. Same situation with anaconda and El Captain. Glad I read the comments before removing things on the answer above.

Comment: My anaconda folder is not at $HOME so just note that the export command needs to reflect the anaconda folder location

Comment: The pitfalls of copy-pasta - I was afraid this didn't work for me either ...until I realized I have `anaconda3` not `anaconda`. D'oh. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I put the line in ~/.bash_profile and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, things broke and I'm back. This no longer works (OS Sierra, Anaconda 3)

Comment: This worked for me like a charm.  And I'd been working on it for hours.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added openssl lib path rather than Conda lib (/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q/lib/) to this DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 35):

After Homebrew wouldn't allow me to force link `openssl` the following worked fine:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext \
            --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" \
            --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" psycopg2
```

(this installation succeeded in a `virtualenv` on macOS)

Comment: That's the solution that worked for me so that I could let pip know where my Homebrew libraries.

Comment: This worked for me, too. I am using brew-installed python with a virtualenv (not conda)

Comment: Same, worked for me too. Is there anyway to include these as defaults so I don't have to provide it manually for installs?

Comment: sweetness. I added '--force' to the end. Thanks!

Comment: I tried many answers in many posts and this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 30):

***EDIT: potentially dangerous, read comments first!***

See a much safer answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726895/308315

---

I ran into this exact issue about an hour after you posted it and just figured it out. I am using Mac OS X Yosemite, Python 2.7, and the Postgresql app.

There seems to be a non-working symlink set by default (or I introduced it while troubleshooting), to fix it first remove the incorrect links:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

Then re-link them with (replace YOURUSERNAME with your Mac user name. I found it helpful to use tab to complete each step, to confirm the directory):

```
$ sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

I believe the other solutions didn't work for you because your version is in anaconda.

Comment: The only concern I'd have is that you might now wind up using the anaconda versions of those libraries as opposed to the operating system versions, even for applications that are not python or anaconda.

Comment: Don't rm, just mv. You may find out that you don't actually have files that you want to link to in the next step.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. You can very easily break your system by doing this.

Comment: When you say DON'T DO THIS you are referring to MV the files not creating the symlink correct?

Comment: X.L.'s answer worked for me. I would also be cautious with this answer.

Answer (score 27):

After bashing my head against the wall for a couple hours, these two solutions are guaranteed to work:

**Option 1.** This solves our problem without messing around with environment variables. Run this in your shell:

```
brew install --upgrade openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Boom! This upgrades the symbolic links in `/usr/local` for `libssl` and `libcrypto`. Now `import psycopg2` works like a charm.

**Option 2.** If for some reason you would like to maintain the current symbolic links in `usr/local`, run this command in your shell:

`export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`

Just make sure to replace `$HOME/anaconda/lib` above with the actual lib path. In my case, this was `$HOME/miniconda2/envs/ali/lib`.

This will only work for the shell/bash session you're currently in. To make the change persistent, add the `export` statement to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

**Thoughts:** IMO #1 is the proper way to deal with this problem, but I left #2 in case some people prefer working with environment variables rather than fixing symbolic links (if, for example, they have software with a dependency on the older openssl file versions).

Comment: At brew's output suggestion, I had to change the second line to:

Comment: `brew unlink openssl && brew link --overwrite openssl --force`

Comment: Trying both solution 1 and @uchuugaka's solution failed for me: I'm on OSX Sierra, and when I try to run either of those `brew link` commands, I get an error: `Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure [...]`

Comment: Could be new change in homebrew. That project updates a lot.

Comment: #1 option doesn't work - Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Answer (score 12):

conda install psycopg works for me. It updates the following packages
The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:      3.19.1-py27_0 --> 4.0.5-py27_0
openssl:    1.0.2f-0      --> 1.0.2g-0
pip:        8.0.2-py27_0  --> 8.1.0-py27_0
setuptools: 19.6.2-py27_0 --> 20.2.2-py27_0
wheel:      0.26.0-py27_1 --> 0.29.0-py27_0
```

Comment: This works for me too. I had the same issue, I had previously done ```pip install psycopg2``` with the conda pip: ```$ which pip # //anaconda/bin/pip```

Answer (score 11):

I was having this issue on Mac, trying ln -s was giving me 
ln: /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib: Operation not permitted
I didn't want to mess with my system. Instead What worked for me is to simply install psycopg2-binary :
pip install psycopg2-binary

This installed **psycopg2-binary-2.8.3** version

Answer (score 8):

In relation to X.L.'s answer above, I didn't want to use Anaconda when I'm already using pip, so I just gave it the path to the Postgres libraries which worked for me (I'm using PostgreSQL.app on Mac OS 10.10)...

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to vary Scott Brennstuhl's answer a little: 
1. Remove broken symlinks:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

2. Relink with postgres' included drivers:

```
$ sudo ln -s   /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib    
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib  /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 4):

My flavor of setup was a little different than the OP: I'm using `Postgres.app` on Mac and am within a `virtualenv`; but the symptoms were similar.

For me, this occurred right after updating my `Postgres.app` from 9.3 to 9.5 on my local, and the error clearly showed the `psycopg2` path for `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` was pointing to the old 9.3 data directory location (the `image` referenced in this error?). Adding weird things to my `ENV` or removing symlinks I'm not sure the impact of definitely didn't feel right to me. I solved it by uninstalling then re-installing `psycopg2` the same way I had when it was working - something that doesn't feel very dangerous at all:

```
 # In my virtualenv
 pip uninstall psycopg2
 pip install psycopg2
```

Then I was all good!

Comment: Worked for me once I cleaned pip cache (`pip cache purge`) - the built version in cache was still pointing to the old libssl path.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following to resolve Library not loaded:libssl.1.0.0.dylib error **if you have openssl in /usr/local/Cellar directory**

> 1. sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/<<*version*>>/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
> 2. After doing step 1, if you still get Library not loaded:libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib error. Do the following 
>        sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/<<*version*>>/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib

Answer (score 3):

`brew reinstall openssl postgres` did the trick for me

Comment: I'm using a remote postgres server, but this still did the trick for me. The postgres installation corrected or added the necessary symlinks, I imagine. I like this, as I want homebrew to manage those libs as far as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I updated `openssl` from `1.0.0` to `1.1.1d`, and this fixed my problem:

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

So first for me `openssl` re-install never worked. It was quite irritating that all of the above answers failed for me. To be sure that it's a openssl issue, first, install `psycopg2-binary` using pip

```
  pip install psycopg2-binary
```

After installing `psycopg2-binary`, if you're getting error like `ld: library not found for -lssl`  then do the following

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

if these didn't work then you can try to upgrade `psycopg2` and re-check that issue still there or not.

```
  pip install psycopg2 --upgrade
```

if all the above didn't worked then only try reinstalling `openssl` as mentioned in all above answers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried pip install psycopg2 which was giving similar issues.
Then I tried conda install psycopg2, which worked!
Also make sure the pip you are using belongs to anaconda (which pip)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mac OS Sierra:
and got this error:

```
 Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
```

I found this library in

```
 /Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib
```

I found this solution in internet:

```
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib
```

But this is not a permanent solution. As I have to run the above command whenever I restart my server.

Add the line: 
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL//lib
to 
~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726895 did not) was installing `psycopg2-binary` with: `pip install psycopg2-binary==2.7.6`

This is on MacOS Mohave.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: this pip command will install a package at a specific location:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary -t PATH
```

Where PATH is a path that you specify.

To test this, install the package in a folder on your desktop.
Then put a python script in the same folder that will import psycopg2. It should work with the script being in the same location as the psycopg2 package.

Comments:

This reason we need psycopg2-binary, according to old documentation that I found online:

> "The binary packages come with their own versions of a few C libraries, among which libpq and libssl , which will be used regardless of other libraries available on the client: upgrading the system libraries will not upgrade the libraries used by psycopg2 . Please build psycopg2 from source if you want to maintain binary upgradeability."

Source:
https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/psycopg2/2.7.3/install.html#install-from-source

I realized the issue has been that python's site package directory needs to be referenced. The location for this on my computer is:

```
/Users/my_name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

Now, if you want to use IDLE or say PyCharm as I have been, the installation of psycopg2-binary needs to target this site directory. Additionally, you'll find two folders that appear after installing psycopg2-binary called: psycopg2, psycopg2_binary-2.8.4.dist-info

I spent a long time investigating this issue. The other methods out there were not not resolving the issue as seen above regarding lib ssl and reason image not found.

Setup: macOS Catalina, Python 3.7, PyCharm/IDLE project on Desktop, openssl@1.1/1.1.1d

Answer (score 0):

After trying for more than a day I came to the below solution.

- brew reinstall openssl@1.0
- disable csrutil -> google it how to disable it, so that we could copy something
  to /usr/lib
- copy libssl.1.0.0.dylib to /usr/lib 
       I did- sudo cp 
             /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
- copy libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib to /usr/lib
       I did- sudo cp 
              /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib

Similarly, if you face issue for **Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib**
just change the version from 1.0 to 1.1 of openssl and copy libssl.1.1 instead libssl.1.0 and libcrypto.1.1 instead libcrypto.1.0.0

Done you are all set to enjoy psycopg2 in mac.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew upgrades default openssl from v1.0 to v1.1. If you tried @Scott solution to upgrade openssl:

```
brew install --upgrade openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

you may run into ssh problem. You need to upgrade openssh as well.

```
brew upgrade openssh
```

according to this blog: https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/2019/12/17/git-fetch-libssl-error.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem after running `brew upgrade`, which updated openssl from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1. That causes the error in the question because I'm using pyscopg 2.7.4, which is pinned to [openssl@1.0](https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/). More recent versions of psycopg (>2.8) are pinned to [openssl@1.1](https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2019/04/14/psycopg-281-282-released/).

So your options in this situation are to upgrade your psycopg version to 2.8.1 or later (in your Pipfile/Pipfile.lock, etc.), or force brew to keep using openssl@1.0 with this command, taken from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/47348#issuecomment-560001981:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/64555220bfbf4a25598523c2e4d3a232560eaad7/Formula/openssl.rb -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ psycopg2==2.7.6.1.dev1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that was originally posted in this thread. I traced it back to a problem with `libpq`. For me, the solution was to run

`brew install postgresql`,

after which `psycopg2` worked like a breeze.