# Trying to install psycopg2 in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, psycopg2

I have been trying to install psycopg2 in PyCharm, but I keep running into this error:

```
>>> pip install psycopg2
File "<input>", line 1
pip install psycopg2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've already managed to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv outside of PyCharm. However, PyCharm doesn't recognize that installation, and it seems that I have to install it separately from inside PyCharm. As a result when I run the project in PyCharm I get this error: `ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'`. I'm a beginner to PyCharm--and, frankly, to Python development--so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Given your use of '>>>', it appears that you are trying to install `psycopg2` from within Python. Exit the Python shell and run the command.

If you are in IPython, you can prepend your command with an exclamation to run it as a command instead of as Python code:

```
In[1]: !pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I'm trying to install `psycopg2` from within the Python Console in PyCharm. That command didn't work unfortunately, and I'm getting this error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: In which case you'll need: $ pip install psycopg2 (Note that you don't type the '$' sign, it just indicates that you need to execute this command from a terminal window).

Comment: That worked once I switched my interpreter to Python 2.7.6. However, I ran  into the same errors that I did when I switched my interpreter to my virtualenv, which already had all the packages I needed installed

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors?  You may also want to refer to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Comment: Once, I ran the `pip install psycopg2` command in my terminal, I had to switch my interpreter to Python 2.7.6 to pick up that new installation. However, I'm getting an operation error when I run my project with either Python 2.7.6 or my virtualenv as my interpreter. Here's the error: `peewee.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: You may want to refer to the Psycopg2 Installation Instructions http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html.

Comment: I've got it installed now. It's just that in doing so, a new issue has popped up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426181/peewee-operationerror-in-pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ pip install psycopg2==2.4.5
```

or

```
$ pip install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/psycopg2/psycopg2-2.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks, Vaibhav, but for some reason I'm getting syntax error with these commands, too.