# Fish shell cannot find opencv's dylib files

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, fish

I just installed Opencv 3.2 using conda forge on Anaconda with python 3.6. While using bash to run `import cv2` works alright, running this command on fish shell outputs this error message.

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/vicarious/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_hdf.3.2.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/vicarious/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
Reason: image not found
```

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib) question and added `set -x DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /Users/vicarious/anaconda/lib/ $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` fish config file which did not help.

I also disabled MacOS Sierra SIP as it apparently does not let DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH to be changed. But I still get the same error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using fish as my default shell on macOS Sierra 10.12:

```
python
Python 3.6.0a3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 12 2016, 15:51:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
3.2.0
>>> exit()
```

If it works in bash but not fish then your bash environment is probably defining an environment var that isn't present in the fish environment or has a different value. Also, I installed opencv2 using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`. If you built it from source or installed it in some other manner that is likely a factor.