# import _mysql in python 3

Tags: mysql-python

I am trying to make and connect to a local database. I am using Anaconda version  1.6.14 together with python 3.6.5 - I already have 5.7.23 installed in my path, together with mysqlclient==1.3.13.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
config_path = cwd + '/config.ini_sample'
print(config_path)

import configparser
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


config_fields = ['host', 'port', 'user', 'passwd', 'database', 'sql_type',
                 'charset']

def read_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    with open(str(config_path)) as fp:
        config.read_file(fp)
        actual_config_fields = config['Global'].keys()
        missing = set(config_fields) - actual_config_fields
        if missing:
            print('The configuration file (%s) ' % str(config_path) +
                  'is invalid. ' +
                  'Missing fields %s' % (', '.join(map(repr, missing))))
            raise Exception
        return config

def setup_database_connection():
    global _engine, _session

    config = read_config()
    connection_url = ("{sql_type}://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/"
                      "{database}?charset={charset}")
    connection_url = connection_url.format(**config['Global'])
    _engine = create_engine(connection_url, encoding='utf-8')
    _session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

setup_database_connection()
```

config.ini.sample is

```
[Global]
host = localhost
user = your_user
port = 3306
passwd = your_pass
charset = utf8
database = erhvervsdata
sql_type = mysql
```

and the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6dff59dfc481> in <module>
     35     _session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
     36 
---> 37 setup_database_connection()
     38 

<ipython-input-4-6dff59dfc481> in setup_database_connection()
     32                       "{database}?charset={charset}")
     33     connection_url = connection_url.format(**config['Global'])
---> 34     _engine = create_engine(connection_url, encoding='utf-8')
     35     _session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
     36 

/anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
    423     strategy = kwargs.pop('strategy', default_strategy)
    424     strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy]
--> 425     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
    426 
    427 

/anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
     79                 if k in kwargs:
     80                     dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k)
---> 81             dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
     82 
     83         dialect_args['dbapi'] = dbapi

/anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py in dbapi(cls)
    100     @classmethod
    101     def dbapi(cls):
--> 102         return __import__('MySQLdb')
    103 
    104     def do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):

/anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in <module>
     16 from MySQLdb.release import __version__, version_info, __author__
     17 
---> 18 import _mysql
     19 
     20 if version_info != _mysql.version_info:

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/Virk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Answer (score 1):

Try to include all the anaconda libraries with

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```