# Django/PostgreSQL Project unable to run due to 'missing' libssl file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, macos, libssl

I'm trying to set up a local version of a web project made with Django and PostgreSQL.

However, when I'm trying to 'run' it (makemigrations, runserver..) I get the following errors:

```
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my_username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/my_username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
      Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/my_username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/my_username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
      Reason: image not found
```

I haven't included the full Traceback for readability reasons, but if needed I'll include it.
Openssl, PostgreSQL and the psycopg2 module seems to be installed properly. I did the following commands:

```
$ ls /usr/lib | grep "ssl"   


libboringssl.dylib
libssl.0.9.7.dylib
libssl.0.9.8.dylib
libssl.35.dylib
libssl.43.dylib
libssl.44.dylib
libssl.46.dylib
libssl.dylib

$ otool -L -v /Users/my_username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so

/Users/quentinbackaert/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so:
        libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.12.0)
        libssl.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
        libcrypto.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.0.0)
```

So i think the file in the proper version (1.1) is missing or not in the right place. I checked several other posts with the same issues, but wasn't able to solve the problem. I'm on MacOS Catalina.

Edit:
I tried adding the following to my environement:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/lib/
```

This is the path where the libssl file it's looking for is actually situated. But now the error changed, It's basically the exact same error but now it's looking for *libpq.5.dylib*
I assume it worked since it's now looking for another file, but now it's looking for libpq.5.dylib which was in /usr/bin. So I think I need a way to put libssl.1.1.dylib into /usr/bin but it won't let me.

```
$ sudo cp libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/lib
cp: /usr/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib: Read-only file system
```

Edit:

It SEEMS I have solved the issues by deinstalling psyco_pg2 and psyco_pg2 binary, and reinstalling with:

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

I guess it solved the issues, weirdly enough the only thing I changed is pip3 instead of pip. I GUESS it solved the issues since I'm now having other issues unrelated to psyco-pg2

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Comment: The poster on this question is using anaconda, I don't. Also as I said, I already checked several other posts with a similar issue, with no luck.

Comment: @Melvyn first psycopg2, then I tried installing psycopg2-binary but it didn't change anything

Comment: Please add the output of `otool -L /path/to/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so`

Comment: @Melvyn I edited my post with the output of this command

Comment: oops, edited it again. I made a typo in the command.

Comment: Ok, that looks reasonably sane. And this one? `otool -L /path/to/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libpq.5.11.dylib`?

Comment: @Melvyn it seems the file .dylibs does not exist. I updated my post with some new informations